# selectinput not field backend data react admin

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I am using React-admin.
In the SelectInput component I have several values, how to automatically select the desired value depending on the data, come from the backend.

```
<FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, getSource, scopedFormData }) => {
      console.log(scopedFormData);
      console.log(choices);
      return (
        <Box display={"flex"}>
          <Box flex={"5"} className={classes.cardItem}>
            <SelectInput
              source={getSource("resource")}
              onChange={(val) => metod(val)}
              label="Ресурс"
              choices={choices}
              optionText="name"
              optionValue="id"
              record={scopedFormData}
              inputText={inputText}
              clearAlwaysVisible={true}
              fullWidth
              required
            />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );
    }}
</FormDataConsumer>
```